# Programmatic UI design

Tags: android, android-layout

Why should I use the programmatic approach to design a GUI in the android studio instead of using the XML approach which is quite easy and easy to maintain? I am quite confused about its practical usage.

Comment: Just start using XML layouts by default. When you can do it with them then do it. You will notice when you need to do something programmatically because then there is no way doing it with XML layouts.
Practice and experience is all you need and you will get it with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't...You should know the differences between the two approaches and select the one that suits you better at each occasion.

Using xml makes it much easier and much faster to see the changes you are making as you can see your UI change as you type. In a programmatic approach you have to build the project every time to see the effect of your changes which makes it a pain and as your UI gets bigger and more complex it is hard to keep track of everything in your mind while coding.

However the programmatic approach makes the UI load much faster. Specially if your UI has many views. The `findViewById` method is quite expensive performance wise. Also the less xml files you have the smaller your apk file will be.

Another benefit of the programmatic approach is that if you use proguard the code that builds the UI will be obfuscated making the apk size even smaller and not readable. If you use xml files and someone reverse engineers your app they will see your xml files easily as they don't get obfuscated. This makes it easier for them to figure out how your app works and mess with it. Does that matter to you?

Those are the main differences so the choice is yours depending on your needs and likings.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Whenever you need to create/change/remove UI elements dynamically during runtime.

Comment: But the similar work can be done in xml, isn't it?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes: Usually you can do most of your UI in XML. No: Sometimes you want to change your UI dynamically during runtime. In this case you cannot use a static/unchangeable XML layout, but you have to "program the changes" by using code.

Comment: I mean most often you just use different view types in a RecyclerView for that, although I guess not always